# Variadic Parameters - Compiler Error cannot convert value of type '[Int]' to expected argument type 'Int'

Tags: swift

New to swift. Not sure why the complier is giving the error for the code below.:

```
func addNumbers(numbers: Int ...) -> Int {
    var total : Int = 0
    for number in numbers {
        total += number
    }
    return total
}

func multiplyNumbers(numbers: Int ...) -> Int {
    var total : Int = numbers [0]
    for (index,number) in numbers.enumerate()  {
        if index == 0 {
            continue
        }
        total *= number
    }
    return total
}

func mathOperation(mathFunction: (Int ...) -> Int, numbers: Int ...) -> Int {
     return mathFunction(numbers)
}
```

Error:

> error: cannot convert value of type '[Int]' to expected argument type
>   'Int'
>        return mathFunction(numbers)

Comment: `mathFunction: (Int ...)`... expects a variadic argument of _single_ `Int` types, whereas `numbers` is an `Int` array; e.g., the following signature is valid (but perhaps not as you intended) `func mathOperation(mathFunction: ([Int]) -> Int, numbers: Int ...) -> Int { ... }`. This is possibly unexpected as `numbers` in `mathOperation` is a variadic parameter, but this is only in effect when calling the function: variadic parameters aren't really a type, so once `numbers` enter "an instance of the function", it's an array.

Comment: Swift varargs are not as easily interchangeable as in Java for example, you cannot simply pass an array in

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Swift varargs aren't quite as easy to work with. I would change the parameter types to Arrays. Here's a working fix:

```
func addNumbers(numbers: [Int]) -> Int {
    var total : Int = 0
    for number in numbers {
        total += number
    }
    return total
}

func multiplyNumbers(numbers: [Int]) -> Int {
    var total : Int = numbers [0]
    for (index,number) in numbers.enumerate()  {
        if index == 0 {
            continue
        }
        total *= number
    }
    return total
}

func mathOperation(mathFunction: [Int] -> Int, numbers: Int ...) -> Int {
     return mathFunction(numbers)
}

print(mathOperation(multiplyNumbers,numbers: 3,24))
```

This will print out `72`

Answer (score 1):

As dfri mentioned, the variadic parameters are typed as arrays, so it should actually be `mathFunction: [Int] -> Int, numbers: Int ...)`

EDIT:

This requires changing the signature of addNumbers and multiplyNumbers to take in `[Int]`, because of the reason above.

Comment: This won't work. You'd need to change the parameters of the other two functions as well.

Comment: Ah yeah, makes sense.