# How to pass an array to a function which is variadic in Swift?

Tags: swift, variadic

How to pass an array to a function which is variadic?

```
static func apply<T>(fn: (T ...) -> T, xs: [T]) -> T {
    return fn(xs)  // gives '[T]' is not convertible to 'T' error
}
```

I am trying to get something like

```
func foo(n: String ...) -> String {
    return n.joined(separator: ", ")
}

foo(n: "a", "b", "c")

apply(foo, "a", "b", "c")  // "a, b, c"
```

---

I would like to keep the function signature of `fn: (T ...) -> T` as variadic if possible, changing the rest to suit as needed to fix the issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24024428/2907715

Comment: I cannot change the function signature for apply if possible. I want to keep `fn: (T ...)` as is.

Comment: Swift currently has no way to splice array into variadic parameters.

Comment: You should call `apply` this way `apply(fn: foo, xs: ["a", "b", "c"])` since `xs` is defined as an array

Comment: If I use `apply<T>(fn: (T ...) -> T, xs: T ...) -> T`, is it possible to achieve the result?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Variadic Parameters - Compiler Error cannot convert value of type '\[Int\]' to expected argument type 'Int'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35373083/variadic-parameters-compiler-error-cannot-convert-value-of-type-int-to-exp)

Comment: @PGDev: This is not a duplicate of the linked question. I want to keep the `fn` as variadic function.

Comment: You **cannot** pass an array to a function taking a variadic parameter, as explained in the referenced Q&As. There is no way around this.

Comment: If for your situation you know the count of `xs` is small (< 20 for instance), a workable but **ugly** solution would be to `switch` on `xs.count` and break out the array into individual variables: eg.  `case 5: return fn(xs[0], xs[1], xs[2], xs[3], xs[4])`.  In that case, you might want to make `apply` return an *optional* so that you could return `nil` for cases when `xs` has too many members.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provided the variadic function returns the same type as its parameter (like your 'foo' example), then you can define apply like this :

```
func apply<T>(_ f:(T ...) -> T, with elements:[T]) -> T {
   var elements = elements

   if elements.count == 0 {
       return f()
   }

   if elements.count == 1 {
       return f(elements[0])
   }

   var result:T = f(elements.removeFirst(), elements.removeFirst())

   result = elements.reduce(result, {f($0, $1)} )

   return result
}
```

then to call it :

```
func foo(_ n: String ...) -> String {
    return n.joined(separator: ", ")
}

func sum(_ numbers:Int ...) -> Int {
    return numbers.reduce(0, +)
}

let arrInt = [3, 5, 10]
apply(sum, with: arrInt) // 18

let arrString = ["apple", "peer", "banana"]
apply(foo, with: arrString) // "apple, peer, banana"
```

Comment: "Provided the variadic function returns the same type as its parameter" and is associative :)